# bind the same vector in multiple rows

Tags: r

I have this vector:

```
Vec=c("a" , "b", "c ", "d")
```

I want this as data frame:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    a    b    c    d
[2,]    a    b    c    d
[3,]    a    b    c    d
[4,]    a    b    c    d
[5,]    a    b    c    d
```

Comment: quick and dirty:
`df <- t(data.frame(Vec,Vec,Vec,Vec,Vec))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option:

```
t(replicate(5, Vec))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
#[2,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
#[3,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
#[4,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
#[5,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d"
```

Comment: and then add `as.data.frame()` for `as.data.frame(t(replicate(5, Vec)))` to yield the data frame.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `rbind` and `do.call` would be:

```
do.call(rbind, replicate(5, Vec, simplify = FALSE))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
[2,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
[3,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
[4,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
[5,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d"
```

You can replace `5` with any number you like.

`replicate` returns the Vec 5 times in a list (`simplify = FALSE` creates the list) . These elements are `rbind`-ed using `do.call`.

**Update:**

Actually using `matrix` is probably the best:

```
> matrix(Vec, nrow=5, ncol=length(Vec), byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
[2,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
[3,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
[4,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d" 
[5,] "a"  "b"  "c " "d"
```

Change the `nrow` argument to whatever number you want and you ll have it ready.

All 3 answers will need to use `as.data.frame` to convert to a data.frame so I am excluding this from the microbenchmark:

**Microbenchmark**

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(t(replicate(5, Vec)),
+                                do.call(rbind, replicate(5, Vec, simplify = FALSE)),
+                                matrix(Vec, nrow=5, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE),
+                                times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
                                                expr    min     lq      mean median     uq      max neval
                                t(replicate(5, Vec)) 52.854 59.013 68.393740 63.374 70.815 1749.326  1000
 do.call(rbind, replicate(5, Vec, simplify = FALSE)) 18.986 23.092 27.325856 25.144 27.710  105.708  1000
       matrix(Vec, nrow = 5, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)  1.539  2.566  3.474166  3.079  3.593   29.763  1000
```

As you can see the `matrix` solution is by far the best.

Comment: Yeah `matrix()` is by far the most sensible way with its magical recycling powers.